# error during django template rendering

Tags: python, django

working in django tutorials and this error in template rendering appears

> NoReverseMatch at /music/1/ Reverse for 'favorite' with arguments
>   '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

this is a detailed view for the problem

```
Error during template rendering
In template E:\Codes\bucky - Django Tutorials for Beginners\website\music\templates\music\detail.html, error at line 10
Reverse for 'favorite' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

1   <img src="{{ album.album_logo }}">
2   
3   <h1>{{ album.album_title }}</h1>
4   <h2>{{ album.artist }}</h2>
5   
6   {% if error_message %}
7       <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
8   {% endif %}
9   
10  <form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="post">
11      {% csrf_token %}
```

this is my music/urls.py

```
app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail ,name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/favorite/$', views.favorite ,name='favorite'),

]
```

the detail.html file where the error appear in the form

```
<img src="{{ album.album_logo }}">

<h1>{{ album.album_title }}</h1>
<h2>{{ album.artist }}</h2>

{% if error_message %}
    <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
        <input type="radio" id="song{{ forloop.counter }}" name="song" value="{{ song.id }}">
        <label for="song{{ forloop.counter }}">
            {{ song.song_title }}

            {% if song.is_favorite %}
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png">
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <br>
    {% endfor %}

    <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

Comment: Try without namespace: {% 'favorite' album.id %}.

Comment: The error message does not match your code.